# deploying angular2 and nodejs project on firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

I am working on a project where in my front end I'm using angular 2 and my back end node.js.
So basically I want my back end to talk to firebase and return the result to my front end (angular 2) how can I deploy these two separate projects to firebase?

Thank you so much pardon my English

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not compulsory that if you are using Firebase to store data then you must use Firebase for the frontend and backend deployment too. You can use other Services like **heroku**, which is much easier to work with.

If you still want to work with Firebase. here's what you can do.

Run **ng build** in your angular 2 code. This will create a new **dist** **folder** in you application. Serve the contents of the dist folder as static.

You can follow the complete procedure steps here ***[https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)***